# PySide не "видит" файл со стилями

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, pyqt, pyside2

Подключаю в Pyside отдельный файл qss

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    File = QtCore.QFile("styles/styles.qss")
    qss = QtCore.QTextStream(File)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss.readAll())
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Содержимое qss

```
 QListWidget, QListView, QTreeWidget, QTreeView {
outline: 0px;
}
QListWidget {
    min-width: 120px;
    max-width: 120px;
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
QListWidget::item:selected {
    background: rgb(52, 52, 52);
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(9, 187, 7);
}
HistoryPanel::item:hover {background: rgb(52, 52, 52);}
QStackedWidget {background: rgb(30, 30, 30);}
QLabel {color: white;}
```

Получаю ошибку

```
QIODevice::read (QFile, "styles/styles.qss"): device not open
```

Файл на месте,всё ок. Не пойму, что не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё,разобрался

```
File = open("styles/style.qss",'r')
with File:
    qss = File.read()
app.setStyleSheet(qss)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Для `QFile` нужно сначала [open](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open-2) вызвать с обязательным указанием режима:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile

f = QFile("styles/styles.qss")
f.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
print(f.readAll())
```

Проще использовать [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) из питона:

```
with open("styles/styles.qss") as f
    print(f.read())
```